# Coordinates of A Boxplot Legend with Categorical X-Axis

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I have a boxplot with 2 bars:

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$qsec)
```

I want to add a legend to the bottom right using coordinates.
How do I know what is the x-value of the x,y coordinate for the legend function (x) below?

```
legend(x,15,legend=c("mpg","qsec"))
```

Comment: I think each box is centered on an integer value and integers start at 1 with the left-most box and increase consecutively moving to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use coordinates?  If you drop that condition, it's easy:  Use the name "bottomright" instead, i.e.

```
legend("bottomright", legend = c("mpg","qsec"))
```

You can use the `inset` argument if you don't want it precisely in the corner, e.g.

```r
boxplot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$qsec)
legend("bottomright", legend = c("mpg","qsec"), inset = c(0.01, 0.02))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>